# how to prevent rendering child components if they returns null

Tags: reactjs

From `Parent` component, I pass domain props to `Child` component. In `Child`, if a website exists with the domain, it returns the website's information. Otherwise, it returns null. When it returns null, I don't want to render the `Child` component on `Parent` component.

How can I prevent rendering it?

```
class Parent extends Component {

  ...

  render() {
    const { domain } = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            <Child domain={domain} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  ...
  Here, check if the website exists
  ...

  render() {
    const { domain } = this.props;
    const { isExist } = this.state;

    return {isExist ? <div>Yes</div> : null}
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A child that returns `null` in `render` isn't rendered to DOM. This is already done in original code but there are problems with syntax.

Braces should be used only inside JSX elements to wrap JS expressions. They are treated as object literal here:

```
return {isExist ? <div>Yes</div> : null}
```

It should be:

```
return isExist ? <div>Yes</div> : null
```

Then it [works as intended](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h1fxqu).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways: define a `shouldComponentUpdate` method, or use a pure component.

Comment: See http://lucybain.com/blog/2018/react-js-pure-component/ for examples.